# update и ошибка Subquery returned more than 1 value

Tags: sql

when i try to update

Subquery returned more than 1 value. This is not permitted when the subquery follows =, !=, <, <= , >, >= or when the subquery is used as an expression.

```
UPDATE pointlive_ext
SET Nomer_marshruta = (SELECT nomermarsh FROM #nt
WHERE #nt.period_idd = pointlive_ext.period_id)
```

Comment: Please **edit your question** and add a tag for the database you're using. Thanks.

Comment: What is your question? Obviously, yout table `#nt` contains multiple rows for one `period_idd`, so you cannot say `Nomer_marshruta` shall be the `nomermarsh` of *the* row for the matching `period_idd`; there can be many rows for the matching `period_idd`.

Answer (score 0):

```
update pointlive_ext set Nomer_marshruta =g.nomermarsh from pointlive_ext a inner join  #nt g on a.period_id=g.period_idd
```

Comment: This would be a better answer if you explained how the code you provided answers the question.